# useState only functions on second click when updating the current information in an API link through Hooks and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I am learning React and I have been facing the following issue with useState: when the button is clicked the data is set to null (which is the initial state in the hook) after the first click but then on the second click I get the result I want (I want to increment only the value of stars on click). I understand that since useState and setState are just queues, they only update in an asynchronous manner. I have tried using useEffect to mitigate this but the program ends up rendering before the button is clicked. Here is my code :

```
const UniversityDetails = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const {data,isPending} = useFetch("http://localhost:8000/universities/" + id);
    const [stars,setStars] = useState(null);
    const [name,setName] = useState(null);
    const [Location,setLocation] = useState(null);
    const [students,setStudents] = useState(null);
    const [foundation,setFoundation] = useState(null);

   const handleClick = () => {
            const things = {stars, name, Location, students, foundation};
            fetch("http://localhost:8000/universities/4", {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(things)

            }).then(() => {
                data &&
                setStars(data.stars + 1)
                setName(data.name)
                setLocation(data.Location)
                setStudents(data.students)
                setFoundation(data.foundation)
            }).catch(err => {
                if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
                    console.log('fetch aborted')
                } 
            })
   }
```

Here is where I call handlclick:

```
    return (
        <div className="UniversityDetails">
            {isPending && <h2>Loading...</h2>}
            {data &&
                <article >
                <h1> {data.name}</h1>
                    <h3> Total stars: {data.stars}</h3>
                    <h3> Number of students: {data.students}</h3>
                    <h3>Year of foundation: {data.foundation}</h3>

                </article>}
            {data && <button onClick={handleClick}>

                <h4 style={{color:"white",fontWeight: "bold",fontSize:17}}>UPVOTE !</h4>
                <h4 style={{fontSize:13,marginTop:1,color:"white",fontWeight: "lighter"}}>Total stars: {data.stars}</h4>
            </button> }
        </div>
    );
};

export default UniversityDetails;
```

Comment: Add a loading state and disable the button from several clicks. Place all your data in one object because each `set` will trigger a render. In your example you have 5 times component rerendering when you could only render once by `setState({stars, name, location, students, foundation})`.

Comment: `onClick={handleClick}` change this to `onClick={() => handleClick()}`
Also for me its is not good to setState to null at the initial render 
If you already know the data type you can setState to their corresponding data type.

Eg 
`const [name, setName] = useState('') `
`const [students,setStudents] = useState([]);`